# Payment gateway integration problem in redirection from back-end to front-end in web application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, payment-gateway

In one of my web application which make use of spring boot and angular 6 environment I am trying to integrate the payu payment gateway. Now the problem is they will post the success capture or failure capture data to whatever URL provided by our application.

What is the url we need to give them to post the data. Is it a backend url Or front end url.

If it is backend url,  then once data is received in spring boot we will save the data to the db after that how to change the page in the front end. ( in angular)

Please help me and guide me to proceede.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get solution here?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for FE url. You can give BE url itself. Ideally, its better to pass a callback function to payU api, in that callback capture the success response and trigger BE api call from there. 
Note: You should check with PayU whether it is possible to pass callback method to them.